# Bind the same Source Property to multiple Target

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a main UI container (let's say a Canvas) with a UI switch capability:

1. a Zoom Out to set the current UI to a custom `FlipControl`
2. a Zoom In to set the current UI to a custom `Panorama` Control

Both SelectedItem properties are bound to a  CurrentItem property in my Main UI ViewModel, but while switching from the FlipControl to the Panorama (or viceversa) the property is updated at first with the right selected value, and in a second time with null (I suppose due to some visibility change logic).

Is there a way to avoid null SelectedItem on interface switch?

The code:

```
<controls:ZoomBox>
<controls:ZoomBox.Levels>

<controls:FlipControl Grid.Column="1" Items="{Binding FilteredCards,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  IsManipulationEnabled="True" LabelVisibility="Collapsed"
                                      SelectedElement="{Binding CurrentCard,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<controls:Panorama Items="{Binding FilteredCards,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="400" 
                              SelectedElement="{Binding CurrentCard,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"  />

</controls:ZoomBox.Levels>
</controls:ZoomBox>
```

Panorama SelectedElement Dependency Property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedElementProperty = 

DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedElement",typeof(Card),typeof(Panorama), new PropertyMetadata(default(Card)));

public Card SelectedElement
{
       get { return (Card)GetValue(SelectedElementProperty); }
       set { SetValue(SelectedElementProperty, value); }
}
```

FlipControl SelectedElement Property

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedElementProperty = 

DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedElement",typeof(Card),typeof(FlipControl), 
                            new PropertyMetadata(default(Card)));

public Card SelectedElement
{
       get { return (Card)GetValue(SelectedElementProperty); }
       set { SetValue(SelectedElementProperty, value); }
}
```

And the Binding (the same for both the controls)

```
<ListView x:Name="itemsControl" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=mainControl,Path=SelectedElement,Mode=TwoWay}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=mainControl,Path=Items}" />
```

The ZoomBox switches the Current Level changing between the controls (using the same instances initialized once in the start up).

Comment: The code is **always** relevant ;)

Comment: @PatriceGahide you're right :)

Comment: The problem is switch from ListView to ComboBox but you don't post the combobox.

Comment: Do you actually have a question? I couldn't find one.

Comment: @Blam the controls are a FlipControl and Panorama, they have a ListView inside shown in the question.

Comment: @Sheridan Is there a way to avoid null SelectedItem on user interface switch?

Comment: The stated question is "but while switching from the ListView to the ComboBox (or viceversa) the property is updated at first with the right selected value, and in a second time with null".

Comment: @Blam updated with the actual controls. The ListView is inside both of them.